# Is there an option to get the TFS changeset number automatically?

Tags: tfs

I would like to present in my GUI the changeset number in the TFS that compiled into that code version without hard-coding it each time I update something in the code, check-in, and re-compile.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The build number would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you need this? In MSBuild there is a property called GetVersion, which has the changeset of the build in the format Cxxxxx.

If you need the actual changeset from API in C#, you can use this:

```
VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)tfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
int latestId = vcs.GetLatestChangesetId();
```